# How does kernel work in unsharp masking?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I applied the kernel below to the picture for unsharp masking [image]

```
k = [-1 -1 -1; -1 8 -1; -1 -1 -1]
```

I got [image]

Then I changed 8 to 14. And I got [image]

How does kernel work for unsharp masking the original picture and what does exactly do the number in the middle ?

Comment: Note: In general you'd want for any kernel to have `sum(k(:))==0`, else the images will get way clearer than the original, as in you case with that 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "kernel" you're using is an array which is convolved with the image to create the effect shown.  Image processing using a convolution kernel is extremely common, and the construction of such kernels is itself a huge field.

In the case you've shown, each pixel in the output image is created by multiplying the central pixel of the original image by 8, and then subtracting all the surrounding pixels.  This is a very straightforward high-pass filter, or edge enhancement filter.  Changing the central value will control how much of the original image remains with respect to the edge-enhanced version.

You can read more about image processing kernels here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29